# exception: "mutating method sent to immutable object" which is actually a mutable array

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am trying to change the value to a specific key for a mutable array:

```
NSMutableArray* reversed = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:regions];

[reversed setValue:@"current" forKey:@"region"];
```

But this leads to an uncaught exception:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary
>   setObject:forKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'
>   *** First throw call stack:

Why is it telling me that my NSMutableArray is an immutable object?

Answer (score 2):

`setValue:forKey:` is [documented to do the following](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/setValue:forKey:):

> ```
> setValue:forKey:
> ```
>
> Invokes setValue:forKey: on **each of the array's items** using the specified value and key.

Emphasis mine. Your `NSMutableArray` is mutable, but one of the items contained within is not mutable.

Answer (score 1):

Do you see any mention of `NSMutableArray` in that error message? No. It mentions `__NSCFDictionary`, which is an `NSDictionary` runtime class.

Your call to `setValue:forKey:` is being forwarded to all objects in this array. At least one of those objects is an immutable `NSDictionary`, which throws this exception.